# Is it possible to have a list of primitives in a Dojo filtering select?

Tags: javascript, dojo, primitive, dropdown

My wishful thinking is that, using Dojo's [`dijit/form/FilteringSelect`](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/FilteringSelect.html), I should be able to populate a [`dojo/store/Memory`](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/store/Memory.html) object with an array of primitives (i.e. integers) as-is.

Unfortunately, I think a Memory requires an `idProperty`, and since a primitive has no properties, I have to manually convert my list of primitives into a list of key-values where both the key and value are the same as the primitive value, which in my case is guaranteed to be unique. Another way would be to have a simple `index` or `rowId` property, simply using the index as the key...

But what I really want to know is whether there is a way to do what I want to accomplish without converting my primitives into objects?

Comment: You could create your own store, that assigns an incremental Id for each item. Check https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/creating_stores/index.html